# First order elliptic operator with compact resolvent.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, operator-theory

I am working on Omar Mohsen's article *Witten deformation using Lie groupoids* and having trouble with Proposition 2.1, which says

Let $W$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, $\sharp : T^*W\to TW$ the musical isomorphism given by the Riemannian metric, $\alpha$ a 1-form on $W$ such that

- the form $\mathrm{d}\alpha$ is bounded,
- the section of $\mathrm{End}(\Lambda_{\mathbb{C}}T^*W)$ given by $\mathcal{L}_{\alpha^\sharp}+\mathcal{L}^*_{\alpha^\sharp}$ is bounded,
- $\lVert\alpha\rVert$ is a proper function,

then the operator $d+d^*+c(\alpha)$ on $L^2(\Lambda_{\mathbb{C}}T^*W)$ is a self-adjoint elliptic operator with compact resolvent, where $L^2(\Lambda_{\mathbb{C}}T^*W)$ is the Hilbert space of $L^2$ sections on $\Lambda_{\mathbb{C}}T^*W$, $d$ is the exterior derivative and $d^*$ its formal adjoint, $c(\alpha)=\alpha\wedge\cdot+i_{\alpha^\sharp}(\cdot)$ is the Clifford action.

I can prove that it is self-adjoint and elliptic, but I have no idea of the compactness of its resolvent.

Any help would be grateful!